# Finding Restaurants - Restaurant Guides, Consumer Reviews, Professional Critics’ Reviews?

Tags: restaurants

While visiting a new city, what is a good way to find the best restaurants in the city?

I’m not sure whether consumer-written reviews/ratings (viz on Yelp, Zomato, TripAdvisor, etc.) are reliable.

What about ratings by professional food critics - are they better, or are they also often unreliable? What are the best sources to read reviews by critics on the restaurants in a city? And to discover which critics are the most influential, and reliable (as in independent, unbiased)?

Also, what about restauran guides? (Michelin, Gault Millau, Harden’s, etc.) I’ve also heard it said restuarant guides are not the best source for all cities; that in New York City, for example, the New York Times reviews are more influential than the Michelin guide?

Also, there are many cities for which there are no official guides - particularly in Asia. Are there any good alternate resources in this case?

Comment: Do you look for a 'just normal but decent' meal or a 'three star Michelin guide' meal?  And are you looking for one resource world wide? More details are needed and restrictions otherwise it will be impossible to answer.

Comment: No, not one resource worldwide. Critics are usually local, I guess, and guides are also region specific?

Comment: I’d say good food, in general; not necessarily fine dining.

Answer (score 1):

When looking for restaurant suggestions and reviews, look for local resources.

Online news papers, online tourism web pages and forums; finding good reviewers and restaurant critiques can take a while because you need to know them and if you don't have experience for critique in a city, it's hard to know if they are good or bad.

When reading restaurant critiques, make certain they are not always giving out good reviews or bad reviews, they should have a balanced view.

You can also look for local reddit subreddits; there are probably subreddits for all major cities, where locals help people looking for suggestions (it's always a good idea to do your homework before asking for recommendations). It was my main reference when planning before covid.

Eater.com is also a good resource, mostly for North America, but it sometimes have international listings and recommendations.

Chowhound used to be good but I haven't been there for a while (I think it went bad when they changed (overcomplicated) the site structure.

Guide books are books and only offer a snapshot in time of restaurants in a city; they can quickly become obsolete.

And there are tons of web guides out there, use google and cross reference suggestions.

It's fun planning for restaurants while preparing a vacation; I hope to do that soon.